# Android - getLocation()

Tags: android, android-widget

I have developed an application for my company to track the work done by our agency people and also their location to capture the work places. As we don't want the agency people to browse other website, with the help of network providers we have restricted other websites and allowed only two URL where we run the webservice to store the information captured to the database. But since Android talks to google to get the location we also need map the maps.googleapis.com but when we tried it's not working. Can anyone tell me which URL we should map/whitelist to allow my application to access the google. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i would think u would get coordinates regardless of internet connectivity.  of course i could be wrong.  are you sure you added permissions for location services in the manifest.  i know i have tested gps apps without internet enabled (emulator though).  of course the map wont load but coords should be able to be read from the gps receiver.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about getting your current location, then you should use `LocationManager`(search on SO or google, there are lots of posts about it). Otherweise you can take a look at the [Developer Guide](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata/developers_guide_protocol.html) for Google Maps, but I'm not sure if Android even uses the same API, though.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can only retrieve the coordinates from the devices to your database/server and you'll have the map and with the coordinates you'll know where are they. That would not need a map in the application, and no need for whitelisting the urls. This is another idea, though.